# Displaying image when text is clicked

Tags: css, html, image

I want an image to be displayed when a text is clicked, I have this code at the moment and it works perfectly fine but how would I change the code so I can use a image for my own directory instead of an image from online

```
<iframe src="" name="bettie"></iframe>

<p><a href="http://www.bettiepage.com/images/photos/bikini/bikini1.jpg" target="bettie">Bettie</a></p>
```

Comment: You should learn a bit of Javascript or CSS. Iframes are not intended to be used like that.

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you mean by "use a image for my own directory instead of an image from one"? If you mean you want the user to choose from a list, that's not very clear.

Comment: sorry i meant to say, choose an image in my folders on my computer instead of using that code that finds an image online

Comment: As a starting point use `<input type="file" name="img">` to pick an image file. We need to see your code to deal with the input content to be more helpful.

Comment: `<a href="/someLocalDirectory/myImage.jpg" target="bettie">`

Answer (score 0):

Use the local URL instead of the remote URL.

download this image: http://www.bettiepage.com/images/photos/bikini/bikini1.jpg
place it in the same folder/directory as your index.html page
change `<a href="bikini1.jpg" target="bettie">Bettie</a>`